# how to add reference in visualstudio2005 for vc++ project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

i have created a vc++ console application i need to add .net assembly references.

but when i do the following as project right click->properties->Common 
Properties->references->add references

then i am getting the window as

addrefernce(title)

tabbed window project name and project directory and have empty list

i am unable to find com and .net assemblies. how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since u would like to use .net assemblies in c++ it is managed code.so first in project

properties select the oprion common language runtime support and then include mscorlib.dll in

the c++ file. now go to project properties->right click->add refernce->  now it wil shows all

.net libraries for u.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you :

- [How to: Add or Remove References in
  Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(VS.80).aspx)
- [Adding assemblies to the Add
  References dialog in Visual Studio
  2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2005/11/28/497693.aspx)
- [How to add DLL Reference in Visual Studio 2005?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/3d63b671-a915-4e5e-a0b0-bd49328032d4)
- More [here](http://www.google.lt/search?hl=lt&rlz=1C1GGLS_enLT310LT311&ei=y7MaSrraJYTC-AbAlPXKDg&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&q=visual+studio+2005+add+reference&spell=1).